# How to round off seconds to the nearest minute?

Tags: time, google-sheets, rounding, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am converting [ss] seconds to mm:ss format.
But, I also have to round off the value to the nearest minute.
For example, 19:29 -> 19 minutes and 19:32-> 20 minutes

I have tried using `mround` function. But it did not work.

```
=MROUND(19.45,15/60/24) gives output as 19.44791667.
```

It should come as 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this where B column is formatted as **Time**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), MROUND(A1:A, "00:01:00"), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=TEXT(MROUND("00:"&TO_TEXT(B5), "00:01:00"), "mm:ss")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(MROUND(SUM(TIME(0, 
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(C3:C11), "(.+):"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(C3:C11), ":(.+)"))), "00:01:00"), "[mm]:ss"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I am sorry. it is not working for me. 
Actually, my data is like this https://imgur.com/a/Hy7cMDK. I just want the sum of the total time rounded off to the nearest minute. What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still am not able to get this work.May be its related to the formatting of time. Here is the link to my sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oA9SdNm5lC8aCgijzpetAHSi-LWG-l6kIyYoVCmz_bY/edit#gid=0